# Why the singleton initialization failed (link error)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, singleton

I have defined a singleton as below:

```
struct Conditions {
    bool bMonolithic;
    bool bKeepVersion;
    bool bToc;

    static Conditions& initialize() {
        if (instance == nullptr)
            instance = new Conditions;
        return *instance;
    }
private: 
    Conditions():bMonolithic(false), bKeepVersion(false), bToc(false) {}
    static Conditions* instance;
};
```

When I try to use it, I call the initialize() function:

```
Conditions& kcondition = Conditions::initialize();
```

However, the compiler gives me this error:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static struct Conditions * Conditions::instance" (?instance@Conditions@@0PEAU1@EA)
```

What is the correct way to use the singleton?

Comment: And do you have an instance of it in a c++ file?

Comment: I recommend you consider this design for your singleton. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern/1008289#1008289

Comment: Seconded. Your code is not a good C++ implementation for a singleton.

Comment: @UKMonkey yes, this line `Conditions& kcondition = Conditions::initialize();`

Comment: No, UKMonkey meant where is `Conditions* Conditions::instance;`?

Comment: @StoryTeller yes, you are right, I didn't define that static member.